# Boolean Supplier Java wait until condition is true

Tags: java, boolean

I am trying to get to wait until there exists the condition (theOne, that I am waiting for) in the list of areHere. I am trying to work with BooleanSupplier but can't get it to work, not sure where is my mistake:

```
String theOne = "pika";

final BooleanSupplier itsHere = () -> {
    List <String> areHere = getSomeList();
    for (String eachOne : areHere) {
        if(eachOne.equals(theOne)) { return TRUE; }
    } return FALSE;
};
```

Comment: What is `waitFor`?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but maybe using ```Semaphore()``` might help you [docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

Comment: unfortunately do not quite understand. Why would it not work this way:
do{
            present = getSomeList().stream().filter(s -> 
            s.equals(another)).findAny().isPresent();
}while(present && retryCount > RETRY_CONST);

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca waitFor has a while loop in which it checks whether the condition is true, if it isn't, it sleeps for few seconds and rechecks (up to x times)... 

but I primarily want the rest to work in a way that itsHere is true when the list contains theOne

Comment: @user1418018 there's too much that can go wrong in plenty of places you're not showing. So please [edit] your question to show the `waitFor` and `getSomeList` methods. Also what is `theOne`? Even better please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise you'll only get guesses, not answers.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca getList literally gets a list of Strings, theOne is the String I am looking for. I deleted the waitFor as that's a different question then. Should then this part work? In the sense, if there's 'pika' in the list, BooleanSupplier itsHere would be TRUE?

Comment: @user1418018 yes it should and [it does work](https://ideone.com/CGW620). The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "can't get it to work" - is it always true, always false, throwing an exception, won't compile, etc..

Answer (score 0):

you need to execute supplier. You just declared supplier. But not executed.

```
import java.util.function.BooleanSupplier;
import java.util.*;

public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String theOne = "pika";

    final BooleanSupplier itsHere = () -> {
    List <String> areHere = Arrays.asList("1","2","pika");
        for (String eachOne : areHere) {
            if(eachOne.equals(theOne)) { return Boolean.TRUE; }
        } return Boolean.FALSE;
    };
    
    Boolean result = itsHere.getAsBoolean(); //this code execute supplier and get result.
    System.out.println(result);
    
  }
}
```